# I need advice on changing background of a panel

Tags: c#, list, controls, panel, sender

I currently have a dynamic number of smaller panels being added to large panel.  I have a separate form that returns a list of workspaceID's.

Each WorkSpaceControl has a global variable get,set that stores the workspaceID and I don't see a way to access these in my current scope.

```
WorkSpaceControl wsp = wch.GenerateWorkspaceControl(items, space.Id, space.Name, point);
workSpaceList.Add(wsp);
k++;
col++;

foreach (WorkSpaceControl p in workSpaceList)
{
    ///  allow something to be dragged onto the space and catches something
    p.AllowDrop = true;
    p.DragEnter += formDragEnter;
    p.DragDrop += formDragDrop;

    // Event handler for draggin picturebox 
    p.ItemIcon.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(moveIcon_MouseDown);
    /// event handler for updating icons and quantity based on selected item
    p.Child_ItemIndexChanged += c_SelectedIndexChanged;
    PanelTest.Controls.Add(p);
}

private void btnFindByCustom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ih_FindByCustom findCust = new ih_FindByCustom();
    var result = findCust.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        List<int> workspaceidstohighlight = findCust.workspaceIdsToHighlight;
        //highlihgt the panels in the workspaceidtohighlight
        Panel p = (Panel)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent;
    }
}
```

I need access to all the workspaceControl's that are on panel p.

---

I solved it but it's pretty ugly

```
private void btnFindByCustom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ih_FindByCustom findCust = new ih_FindByCustom();
            var result = findCust.ShowDialog();
            if(result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                List<int> workspaceidstohighlight = findCust.workspaceIdsToHighlight;
                //highlihgt the panels in the workspaceidtohighlight
                if (workspaceidstohighlight.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (WorkSpaceControl list in workSpaceList)
                    {  
                        foreach (int idtohighlight in workspaceidstohighlight)
                        {
                            if (list.WorkspaceID == idtohighlight)
                            {
                                list.backPanel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I wish to not make workSpaceList a global variable but i cannot see any other way.

Does anyone have a "cleaner" way of doing this? I saw somewhere that using linq and creating a join would be a possible solution that I am going to look into.

Comment: I don't understand why I get downvoted so much on this site? isn't the point of this site to ask and learn from people with more knowledge?  That is all i'm trying to do here.  What is so wrong with asking a simple question like this?

Comment: I can understand your frustration, 10-15 days back, I was in the same boat of frustration you are but I've improved and you should too. Ask one thing at a time and also in a better way or in an intelligent way. Even I hate downvoting but everyone is free to do so if your question is not useful or important. Happy

Comment: Thanks, yeah I could have asked it better.  My main concern is I hate global variables and feel there should be a way to do this without having to use a global variable.  Ontop of that the nested foreach cannot be good during runtime. I will look into some kinda linq think eventually to just "join" when id's match or something.  I see what you mean with your edit of my old question.  You clearly have a better way with words then myself.

Comment: I've edited that because no one wants to know/read the story here, they just want a direct question in a direct manner.

Comment: I see, so my current edit on this question is still too much information?

Comment: Yes, it really has.